# Remove Releation Between ArrayList<object>

Tags: java, android

I have two `ArrayList<object>` of same type. I init `ArrayList<object>` B with `ArrayList<object>` A and when I change B, A changes too.
How to copy of A without relation?

Comment: You should do some research before asking in order to not getting negative votes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve my problem with deepCopy i think this is best way But I do not know how much memory it takes.
i solve with this link: [deepCopy](https://alvinalexander.com/java/java-deep-clone-example-source-code)

deep Copy Metode is:

```
   /**
 * This method makes a "deep clone" of any Java object it is given.
 */
public  Object deepClone(Object object) {
    try {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
        oos.writeObject(object);
        ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray());
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(bais);
        return ois.readObject();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

```
            List<String> a = new ArrayList<>();
            a.add("Hello");
            a.add("World");
            List<String> b = new ArrayList<>();
            b.addAll(a);
            b.remove(0);
            System.out.println(a);
            System.out.println(b);
```

Comment: This does not make a deep copy of the objects within the list.

Comment: That would require knowledge of what the objects within the list are, and was not asked for.

Comment: Why you write b.remove(0)?

Comment: `b.remove` shows that I can change `b` without changing `a`, you should run the example provided.

Comment: We want to help but can't understand "doesn't work". If the problem is with your custom `Object` not being serialisable/deep-copyable then may I suggest you ask a new one?  This one is about `ArrayList` and not some hidden `Object` of yours we know nothing about.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for something like this

```
ArrayList<Object> B = new ArrayList<>(A);
```

They must be of the same object type obviously.

Comment: This does not make a deep copy of the objects within the list.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, you need to copy each element yourself, one-by-one, to get a deep copy of an ArrayList. In your own implementation, you have to construct each list element, using either its default constructor or by means of a custom constructor method that you added to the class.

The Collections-method:

```
Collections.copy(ArrayList<T> a, ArrayList<T> b);
```

does *not* perform a deep copy.

Comment: This only makes a deep copy of the objects within the list when they are themselves POJOs https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_old_Java_object

Comment: Dose not work. my arraylist<>b is empty when call this

Comment: This is what I'm explaining in my answer. Atras needs to write the copy-code for the elements in the list himself.

Comment: Ohh.but this solotion is'nt good
Because this process takes a long time